# Column values 2 by 2

Tags: excel, vba

I want to get a column with values 2 to 10 but 2 by 2, I mean, with values (2,4,6,8,10).

I made this code:

```
Sub Contar2()
    For CONTADOR2 = 2 To 10 Step 2
        Dim fila As Integer
        fila = 1
        fila = fila + 1
        Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(fila, 5) = CONTADOR
    Next
End Sub
```

But this returns me the value of 10 in cell(2,5). I don´t know how's reading this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring `fila` in your `For` loop each time, hence each time you are looping, `fila` = 2. You just need to restructure your code a bit. Note, declare outside of the `For` loop and set to 1 before entering the `For` loop. Also, increment *after* inserting the value. See below.

```vb
Sub Contar2()

    Dim fila As Integer
    Dim CONTADOR2 as Long

    fila = 1

    For CONTADOR2 = 2 To 10 Step 2
        Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(fila, 5) = CONTADOR2
        fila = fila + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

**Edit**: Requested to declare `CONTADOR2`, and corrected setting value to `CONTADOR2`

Comment: meaning `CONTADOR2` ?

Comment: @Dean in your code you use `CONTADOR` & `CONTADOR2` without declaring and assigning values to these variables.

Comment: @Error1004 this is purely a copy of the OP original post. The procedure is aimed at giving the OP the needed structure to correct and implement the understanding to their code. If you still deem it absolutely necessary for me to include these declarations I will.

Comment: @Dean no need to take any action.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same **WITHOUT** using a loop...

```
With Sheet1 '<~~ Change this to the relevant sheet
    .Range("E1").Value = 2
    .Columns(5).DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, _
                           Step:=2, Stop:=10, Trend:=False
End With
```

If you have to do this manually, you would do the following

1. Type `2` in cell E1
2. Select the Entire E column.
3. Go to Home Tab – Fill, and click on Series
4. Series in – select Columns.
5. Type – select Linear.
6. Step Value – 2
7. Stop Value – 10
8. Press Ok.

Answer (score 1):

Set `fila` to 1 before loop, move `fila = fila + 1` to the end of the loop like this:

```
Sub Contar2()
    Dim fila As Integer
    fila = 1
    For CONTADOR2 = 2 To 10 Step 2
        Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(fila, 5) = CONTADOR2
        fila = fila + 1
    Next CONTADOR2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Do until` method which is easier to read (in my opinion).

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Value As Long, i As Long

    'i represent the starting row
    i = 1
    Value = 2

    Do Until Value > 10

        With ActiveSheet
            .Cells(i, 5) = Value
            Value = Value + 2
            i = i + 1
        End With
    Loop

End Sub
```

**Notes:**

- In your answer you dont declare `CONTADOR2` & `CONTADOR` and assign values to then
- It s better to use `Option Explicit` at the top of your code to avoid such mistakes
- It s better to avoid `ActiveSheet` and refer to the sheet you want using it s name